# Wireless hotspot problem

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, hot-spot

My Ubuntu laptop connects the Internet though data card. When i try to use it in my mobile by turning on wireless hotspot in laptop i couldn't find any networks in my search result in the phone. I had earlier connect my phone to other networks so it think it is not the problem with my phone. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Lumia710